# using CASE WHEN after CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, case-when

I am trying to use `CASE WHEN` right after CTE definition but the query expects `SELECT` only:

```
WITH A AS
(...) --long query here
CASE WHEN @parameter = '' THEN
SELECT * FROM A 
ELSE
SELECT * FROM A WHERE field like '%' + @parameter + '%'
END
```

Is there a way to make this query work, besides using `OR` statement?

Comment: "besides using OR statement" - UNION

Comment: why are you using a `CASE` to determine a select? why not an `IF/ELSE`?

Comment: If you run this query from some application and define @parameter there, then do this logic on application side before sending query to the database.

Comment: @dbajtr IF doesn't work here either

Comment: @Fabio I don't want to send the whole result set to the application if `@parameter` is not empty

Comment: @YevgeniGrinberg, my point was, that you will have two queries, one without filter and another with filter. Then in your application you will run one query based on the value of parameter. So you will execute your condition before running a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are using CASE WHEN wrong. It is supposed to be used to return a single value, not a table, as part of for example a select clause. It is not intended to be used as flow control to run one of two queries. Use IF for that.

Second, you cannot split a CTE from a select, it is part of the same statement. You can't go "Here is a CTE, now run one of two statements from it", that is not how CTE statements are written. You can reuse a CTE multiple times in a select, but is going to run the whole select, not just part of it.

Some alternate ways that can work

You can use an IF around the whole query, and write it out twice. This way only one version of the query actually runs.

```
IF @parameter = ''
    SELECT (your query here)
ELSE
    SELECT (your query here) WHERE field like ...
```

You could use dynamic SQL, build the first part of the query as a string. Then only add on the where clause if needed, then run the resulting SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OR` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
WITH A AS
    (...) --long query here
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE (field like '%' + @parameter + '%') OR @parameter = '';
```

If `field` is never `NULL`, then this is equivalent to:

```
WITH A AS
    (...) --long query here
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE field like '%' + @parameter + '%';
```

(`LIKE '%%'` matches any non-empty string.)

Comment: @YevgeniGrinberg . . . with the `like` pattern beginning with a wildcard, I'm rather surprised that the impact on performance is noticeable.

Comment: With `OR` the optimizer will ignore the `@parameter = ''` condition and build a plan that makes the comparison for every row in the table.
I want to avoid it when `@parameter` is empty.

Comment: @YevgeniGrinberg . . . My point is that both versions of the query do a full-table scan.  That would typically be significantly more expensive than the `like` -- although if your strings are long, the string operations can start to add up.